Comparing Adjusted $R^2$ Between Totally Different Models
I'm curious as to what extent adjusted $R^2$ can be used to compare models. If I had two different data sets and completely different models for both data sets, could I say something like the the adjusted $R^2$ is higher in model A and therefore model A is better than model B. This sounds reasonable, but is it appropriate? I know we can't compare AIC between different data sets, but can we adjusted $R^2$?

Welcome to CV.  Generally R2 is dataset dependent and can't be compared between datasets.  For  single dataset it shouldn't be used for model selection either

See
